# Hotkey for add/subtract weight brush?

Tags: weight-painting, vertex-weights

I'm using Blender 2.8. Is there a hotkey to switch between the add and subtract brushes in weight paint mode?? I heard you press the number keys, but that doesn't seem to do anything.

Thank you for your time!!!

Comment: The number keys works for me (not on the numpad). Thoose are changing the brush presets. So 8 switch to subtract, 6 switch to mix.

Comment: That's weird maybe it's my computer. Do you need to hold shift?? And we're talking 2.8 right? 8 to 'subtract', which number is supposed to be 'add'?

Comment: In 2.8 doesn't work for me too, only in 2.79.

Comment: Well it's good to know I'm not a lone lol

Answer (score 2):

This answer is for 3.0 and higher version, but as I do frequent weightpainting, I feel it is very relevant.

While it is not possible to map brushes to keys anymore, at least not without python workarounds, you can simply set up keys to switch the Draw Tool to Invert and Smooth mode. I recommend the Modifier Keys for doing so.

[image: Weightpainting Hotkeys to add to Blender 3.0+ for a smooth tool-switching experience]

This leaves you with the Shift Key for smoothing and the Alt Key for removing weights. No tool switching required.

Comment: I use [this script](https://raw.githubusercontent.com/LeanderSilur/Blender-Tools/master/select_weight_paint_brush.py).